# ¿Cómo hacer un COUNT de elementos que pueden aparecer en dos tablas diferentes con un GROUP BY por día?

Tags: mysql, date, tablas, group-by

Tengo una consulta SQL que me dice cuantos personas se han connectados al menos una vez el dia pasado y me gustaría hacer una consulta para saber cuantos personas se han conectado al menos una vez o han leido un email durante el año pasado para cada lenguaje (`Lang`).

Por ejemplo con este schema:

```
CREATE TABLE sessions
    (`App Type` varchar(11), `Lang` varchar(2), `Session ID` int, `session_time` datetime, `User ID` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO sessions
    (`App Type`, `Lang`, `Session ID`, `session_time`, `User ID`)
VALUES
    #july 2021
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960339, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 1292997),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960407, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 1055040),
    ('pwa_android', 'fr', 46960412, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 1120109),
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960391, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 955480),
    ('pwa_android', 'en', 46960389, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 800169),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960353, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 1193745),
    # june 2021
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960339, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 1292997),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960407, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 1055040),
    ('pwa_android', 'fr', 46960412, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 1120109),
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960391, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 955480),
    ('pwa_android', 'en', 46960389, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 800169),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960353, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 12345),
    # june 2020
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960339, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 1292997),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960407, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 1055040),
    ('pwa_android', 'fr', 46960412, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 1120109),
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960391, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 955480),
    ('pwa_android', 'en', 46960389, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 800169),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960353, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 54321)

;


CREATE TABLE unique_open_emails
    (`date` datetime, `lang` varchar(2), `user_id` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO unique_open_emails
    (`date`, `lang`, `user_id`)
VALUES
    ('2016-04-12 00:00:00', 'fr', 115434),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 11357),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 137481),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 10296),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 125772),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 955480),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 9269),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 90716),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 26330),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 89072),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 87416),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 88358),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 102515),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 89867),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 119146),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 133316),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 90095),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 16510),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 21530),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 81581),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'es', 54321),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 29363),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 90326),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 23961),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 89000),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 9484),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 11845),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 41231),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 588),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 16678),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 19674),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 130113),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 84719),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 123252),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 4676),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 113636),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 17452),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 136544),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 15917),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 82787),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 81620),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 135298),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 15643),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 80981),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 51827),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 90554),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 10277),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 24432),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 6651),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 64106),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 119080),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 72659),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 130004),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 22320),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 136966),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 11317),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 79031),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 90800),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 16149),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 61463),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 5383),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 87674),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 10223),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 88100),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 91691),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 89423),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 126),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 86858),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 1419),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 89849),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 15721),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 86444),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 130822),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 73991),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 113969),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 16779),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 71267),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 61067),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 89081),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 24815),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 91928),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 13071),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 1942),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 44012),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 52049),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 6626),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 7034),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 20442),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 75422),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 16673),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 17325),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 7898),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 85226),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 136557),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 134423),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 68723),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'en', 118331),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 91298),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 136046),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 136891),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 9169),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 88946),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 115919),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 44492),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 89783),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 137482),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 10072),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 38636),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 11227),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 108310),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 4700),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 17976),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 8580),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 91316)
;
```

Entonces intenté:

```
SELECT sessions.session_time, `Lang`, (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(`USER ID`))
  FROM sessions s2 JOIN unique_open_emails u ON s2.`User ID`=u.user_id
  WHERE (s2.session_time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(sessions.session_time, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND sessions.session_time)
  OR (u.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(u.date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND u.date)
) AS alive_users
FROM sessions
GROUP BY sessions.session_time, sessions.Lang
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
session_time            Lang    alive_users
2020-06-29T00:00:00Z    en     0   
2020-06-29T00:00:00Z    es     0
2020-06-29T00:00:00Z    fr     0
2021-06-29T00:00:00Z    en     0
2021-06-29T00:00:00Z    es     0
2021-06-29T00:00:00Z    fr     0
2021-07-29T00:00:00Z    en     0
2021-07-29T00:00:00Z    es     0
2021-07-29T00:00:00Z    fr     0
```

Entonces no solamente falta fechas pero tambien los numeros estan falsos.

Pueden probarlo en [este Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/708ad8/5/0)

Utiliso MySQL 5.7

Ademas los verdaderos datos son 37 miliones de lineas para la tabla unique_open_emails solamente entonces la consulta nunca concluirá. No sé si la consulta no está optimizada (indices y esas cosas), entonces si un script irá más rápido.

Comment: Realmente no faltan fechas, ya que estas obteniendo las fechas de `sessions` agrupadas por fecha e idioma, por lo que solo tienes 9 valores diferentes, que son los que obtienes, asi que eso está bien, a no ser que quieras hacerlo de otra manera, entonces deberias cambiar la select.

Comment: Por otra parte, para hacer la consulta que deseas, deberias tener una tabla adicional que es la tabla de los usuarios, ya que tal y como lo tienes, si no existe un usuario que haya iniciado sesión en la tabla de sesiones, no lo va a encontrar en la de emails y no te los va a contar.

Comment: Sin embargo, me faltan las fechas de 2016 de la tabla unique_open_emails, @Marc . No añadí la tabla de usuarios porque no me pareció necesario contar a los que tenían una sesión activa o habían abierto un correo electrónico. Para simplificar, asumo que los usuarios que han iniciado una sesión en la tabla de sesiones están incluidos en la tabla de correos electrónicos si se suscriben a las newsletters.

Comment: Te faltan las fechas de 2016 porque no las estas seleccionando en la query, solo estas seleccionando las fechas de la tabla de sessiones

Comment: Ah, sí, @Marc ¿y cómo puedo integrarlos? Pensé que el JOIN sería suficiente para añadirlos